# How to keep the same width of divs even if the window get smaller

Tags: html, css

I'm building a Wonderfull house in a green field using css, the problem is the nice red roof doesn't want to be fixed on the house. I also do not creating this using responsive technics, i want to make the rectangle and the triangle moving **at the same time** while making the browser window smaller till they (rectangle and triangle) have a certain width and stop moving (and they keep their width while moving).

As you can see, the roof and the house "do not match" if you use the whole browser to see the result it will be ok (roof and house)

Please any help on this ? **Why do the rectangle and the triangle do not move together when i make the browser window smaller ? (please use the full screen if you want to see my snippet)**
Thank you all

```css
.yellow-house{
  width: 100%;
  height: 800px;
  margin: 0 auto;
  background-color: green;
}

.content-rect{
  width: 100%;
  margin: 0 auto;
  
}
.rect{
  min-width: 720px;
  position:relative;
  width: 720px;
  height: 200px;
  margin: 0px auto;
  margin-bottom: 0px;
  border-radius: 20px;
  background-color: #F9C232;
}
.content-tri{
  width: 48.4%;
  margin: 0  auto;
}
.tri{
    position: relative;
    width: 0px;
    height: 0px;
    border-left: 345px solid transparent ;
    border-right: 345px solid transparent;
    border-bottom: 80px solid red;
}
```

```html
<div class="yellow-house">
    <div class="content-tri"><div class="tri"></div></div>
    <div class="content-rect"><div class="rect"></div></div>
</div>
```

Comment: use position absolute?

Comment: this problem is because of your red triangle borders which are in pixels

Comment: @Andrew The reason why i didn't use absolute (for rectangle) for example is for centering it (if i use absolute, i need to put margin-left and put the value to make the rectangle on the center after that if the window is smaller, the rectangle will not move to left (margin-left))

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The issue occurs because `.content-tri` has a dynamic width value e.g. `48.34%` while `.content-rect` has a fixed value e.g. `720px`. This makes the computed margin for the `.content-tri` to change.

Set a fixed value for the width of `.content-tri` and your house will have its roof.

```css
.yellow-house{
  width: 100%;
  height: 800px;
  background-color: green;
}

.content-rect{
  width: 100%;
  margin: 0 auto;
  
}
.rect{
  min-width: 720px;
  position:relative;
  width: 720px;
  height: 200px;
  margin: 0px auto;
  margin-bottom: 0px;
  border-radius: 20px;
  background-color: #F9C232;
}
.content-tri{
  width: 690px;
  margin: 0  auto;
}
.tri{
    position: relative;
    width: 0;
    height: 0;
    border-left: 345px solid transparent ;
    border-right: 345px solid transparent;
    border-bottom: 80px solid red;
}
```

```html
<div class="yellow-house">
    <div class="content-tri"><div class="tri"></div></div>
    <div class="content-rect"><div class="rect"></div></div>
</div>
```

Here is a [jsfiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/6Le1p0bx/) with the demo.

Comment: Awesome now i understood my mistake Thank you very much you're a great css carpenter Tasos

Answer (score 0):

change your css like

```
 .content-tri{
  width: 720px;
  margin: 0 auto;
  }
  .tri{

    border-left: 375px solid transparent;
    border-right: 345px solid transparent;
    border-bottom: 80px solid red;
   }
```